# android File.delete() method return false

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a remote file manager app and I use this method to delete a specific file.

```
String[] executeDeleteFilesFromExpCommands(String path) {
        String[] retval;
        if (!HelperMethods.isStoragePermissionGranted(context)){
            retval = new String[]{"exp_failed", "Permission Denied, you cant Delete files."};
            return retval;
        }
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.canRead()) {
                retval = new String[]{"exp_failed", "File [ "+dir.getName()+" ] inaccessible."};
            }else {
                boolean stat = dir.delete();
                if (stat) {
                    retval = new String[]{"exp_success", "File [ "+dir.getName()+" ] Deleted."};
                } else {
                    retval = new String[]{"exp_failed", "Delete File [ "+dir.getName()+" ] Failed, Try again."};
                }
            }
        }else {
            retval = new String[]{"exp_failed", "File [ "+dir.getName()+" ] not found."};
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

boolean stat = dir.delete();

First time it works perfectly on API 28 and lower. After that I change the compileSdkVersion from 28 to 29.

Then my method stops working.

Please advise.
I change back the compileSdkVersion to 28 and nothing changes.

Comment: You are trying to delete a dir. Not a file.

Comment: And you did not tell the value of path.